# Error http module of Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, webos

I'm developing an application for LG WebOS using Angular2, in Chrome and Firefox  works fine but in TV embedded browser not works. This problem reproducing only when I using HTTP module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1XA3.png)

any solution?, Thanks.

Edited:

LG WebOS not support cookies, my solution was disable cookies from HTTP module of Angular2.

Comment: Please read this before posting, thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

According to the image that you provided the cookie in the browser cannot be read. The issue might be that cookies are disabled in the embedded browser, or you are trying to access a module like localStorage that might not be available in the embedded browser.

This would explain why the calls do not work in all browsers.